# Result Class with Generic Type for both Success and Failure States in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I have implemented some code to capture error and success states returning from the api in kotlin. This is the code I have implemented,

```
interface DataResponse<out L, out R> {
    data class Success<R>(val data: R): DataResponse<Nothing, R>
    data class Error<L>(val error: L): DataResponse<L, Nothing>
}
```

But I don't get why should I specify DataResponse<Nothing, R> and DataResponse<L, Nothing> in front of Success and Error class definitions. I didn't find any supporting answers for this question. Any detailed explanation of why we should specify  DataResponse<Nothing, R> and DataResponse<L, Nothing> in front of Success and Error class would be really appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: We have to put there something, so what would you suggest as an alternative? It sounds even pretty good in English that for the success message there is nothing for the failure type. I guess we could alternatively use `Any?` or `Unit`, but that wouldn't be entirely accurate.